# Set BTsync in 14.04 LTS Ubuntu Server?

Tags: 14.04, server, btsync

I do the following where I found the link source from [here](https://www.getsync.com/platforms/desktop):

1. `wget -O - "https://download-cdn.getsync.com/stable/linux-x64/BitTorrent-Sync_x64.tar.gz" | tar xzf -` in the server home
2. `cd .btsync`
3. `chmod +x btsync`
4. `. btsync` but get *-bash: .: btsync: cannot execute binary file*
5. `btsync` but get *-bash: btsync: command not found*

Positive experiences about similar approach [here](https://community.wd.com/t/bittorrent-sync-installation-script/59014).

How can you setup BTsync in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the files of the tarball and correct permissions/owners

- move extracted directory of tarball to `/usr/local/`
- make symbolic link from `btsync` application from `/usr/local/bsync/...` to `/usr/local/bin/` etc `ln -s ...`